# Yahoo Finance Implied Volatility Calculation

Tags: american-options, rquantlib

On 5/16/16 AXP stock closed with a price of 64.07.
Yahoo Finance reports an implied volatility of 20.58% for this out of
the money call option:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Strike Contract           Last  Bid  Ask  Change %Change Volume Open   Implied
          Name                                                     Intrst Voltlty
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    65.00  AXP161021C00065000 2.85  2.96 3.05 -0.15 -5.00%    9     1773   20.58%

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Tried to see if I could get an implied volatility close to what Yahoo Finance got using this RQuantLib call:

```
AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility(type="call", value=3.05, underlying=64.07,
    strike=65, dividendYield=0.02189756, riskFreeRate=0.3070664,
    maturity=0.4308695, volatility=0.1817867)
```

Instead of getting an implied volatility, I got this error:

```
Error in americanOptionImpliedVolatilityEngine(type, value, underlying,  :
    root not bracketed: f[1e-07,4] -> [3.468527e+00,4.929779e+01]
```

Pricing this option using RQuantLib with Yahoo suggested volatility of 0.2058 produces a higher option price of 7.48:

```
AmericanOption(type="call", underlying=64.07, strike=65,
    dividendYield=0.02189756, riskFreeRate=0.3070664,
    maturity=0.4308695, volatility=0.2058, engine="CrankNicolson")
value  delta  gamma   vega  theta    rho divRho
7.4888 0.8003 0.0313     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

RQuantLib's call to compute implied volatility fails because
the option price of 3.05 if far less than 7.48. I don't have a choice on what option price I enter to compute implied volatility. I have to use
the market price. The market price reported by Yahoo could be wrong. 
Checking with Google Finance and CBOE option quote for this option shows that the Ask price of 3.05 is correct.

With a market price of 3.05, how does Yahoo Finance manage to compute
implied volatility of 20.58%? Is it possibly using a different model than what is used by QuantLib? Or, is there something wrong in my input to
RQuantLib?

Comment: How did you calculate maturity?  
In MATLAB, (datenum('10/21/2016') - datenum('05/16/2016'))/365 = 0.432877. I see same value in Excel too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because your risk-free rate is 0.3070664 (30%)  Try 0.3%

Comment: Changed risk free rate to 0.3% and I get IV of 22.0163% which is close to value published by Yahoo Finance. Thanks.